# jQuery Flotchart is one month off

Tags: jquery, flot

I'm having an issue getting my line chart using FLOT to display properly. Basically it is one month off. What happens is I am storing a history of the amount of users in the system in a SQL database from the current month to the past 12 months. I am retrieving this data from code behind (asp.net) and putting it on the page. All the data is there and all the data shows on the chart but the point for September shows off the XAXIS, the point for August shows on September, the point for July shows on August and so on.

Image: http://www.knowmoreit.com/chartproblem.png

Here is my entire javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var maxDate = new Date();
    var minDate = new Date();

    var data1 = [
        [GetMonth(0), <%= userMonthValues[0] %>],
        [GetMonth(1), <%= userMonthValues[1] %>],
        [GetMonth(2), <%= userMonthValues[2] %>],
        [GetMonth(3), <%= userMonthValues[3] %>],
        [GetMonth(4), <%= userMonthValues[4] %>],
        [GetMonth(5), <%= userMonthValues[5] %>],
        [GetMonth(6), <%= userMonthValues[6] %>],
        [GetMonth(7), <%= userMonthValues[7] %>],
        [GetMonth(8), <%= userMonthValues[8] %>],
        [GetMonth(9), <%= userMonthValues[9] %>],
        [GetMonth(10), <%= userMonthValues[10] %>],
        [GetMonth(11), <%= userMonthValues[11] %>]
    ];

    var dataset = [
        {
            label: "Users",
            data: data1,
            color: "#FF0000",
            points: { fillColor: "#FF0000", show: true },
            lines: { show: true }
        }
    ];

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.plot($("#placeholder"), dataset, {
            xaxis: {
                min: minDate.setMonth(maxDate.getMonth() - 12),
                max: maxDate,
                mode: "time",
                tickSize: [1, "month"],
                monthNames: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
                tickLength: 0,
                axisLabel: "Month",
                axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
                axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
                axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif',
                axisLabelPadding: 5
            },
            yaxis: {
                axisLabel: 'Total',
                axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
                axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
                axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif',
                axisLabelPadding: 5
            },
            series: {
                lines: {
                    show: true,
                    fill: false
                },
                points: {
                    show: false
                }
            },
            grid: {
                hoverable: true,
                mouseActiveRadius: 30,
                borderWidth: 1
            }
        });

        function showTooltip(x, y, contents) {
            $('<div id="tooltip">' + contents + '</div>').css({
                position: 'absolute',
                display: 'none',
                top: y + 5,
                left: x + 5,
                border: '1px solid #fdd',
                padding: '5px',
                'background-color': '#fee',
                'color': '#000000',
                'font-size': '14px',
                opacity: 0.80
            }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
        }

        var previousPoint = null;
        $("#placeholder").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {

            if (item) {
                if (previousPoint != item.dataIndex) {
                    previousPoint = item.dataIndex;

                    $("#tooltip").remove();
                    var x = new Date(item.datapoint[0]),
                        y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2);

                    showTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY,
                                item.series.label + " as of " + $.date(x) + " = " + y);
                }
            }
            else {
                $("#tooltip").remove();
                previousPoint = null;
            }
        });

        $("#placeholder").bind("plotclick", function (event, pos, item) {
            if (item) {
                $("#clickdata").text("You clicked point " + item.dataIndex + " in " + item.series.label + ".");
                plot.highlight(item.series, item.datapoint);
            }
        });

    });

    $.date = function (dateObject) {
        var d = new Date(dateObject);
        var day = d.getDate();
        var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
        var year = d.getFullYear();
        if (day < 10) {
            day = "0" + day;
        }
        if (month < 10) {
            month = "0" + month;
        }
        var date = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;

        return date;
    };

    function GetMonth(subtract) {
        var d = new Date();
        var v = d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - subtract);
        return v;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm missing something, but it looks (almost) correct to me. Generally the point on a month will reflect the data at the beginning of the month, not the entire data for that month. In your case you're going back a month from the current date, though, so it's showing August 29th where it should be Sept. 1st. You also have 13 points on your chart, but only 12 data points, which is why it appears to start in November (I'm guessing it's actually October 29th) instead of October 1st.